# How to model and blend same like the image

Tags: modeling

Hi I tried to model the below plug. But can't able to blend the back with the smaller front as the original. Is there a way? [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with some bevels:

- Create a cube. Mirror it on the X and Z axis.

[image]

- Inset the front face with <kbd>i</kbd> and <kbd>b</kbd> for boundary. Pull it on the Y axis and extrude it.

[image]
[image]

- Select the angle edges, and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to bevel.

[image]
[image]

- Slide the new edges with <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> so decrease the roundness on the back block angles.

[image]

- Inset faces, add edge loops to sharp the angles...

[image]
[image]

Comment: You're right .. it's not an oval, is it? Also .. just noticed a slight downward curvature towards the corners of the more rectangular section.. you need the central division.

Comment: yes the front block is probably flat on the top, and for the downward curvature you're right, I didn't make all the details, but a small extrude should do it

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. Cuboid
2. Bevel verticals
3. Duplicate top face
4. (Shipped add-on) Loop Tools > Circle on the duplicate face, and scale
5. With top and duplicate faces selected, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>> 'Bridge Edge Loops' with a couple of cuts, smoothness, profile roughly adjusted to reference.
6. Subsurface modifier, <kbd>E</kbd> extrusion of top face and then various tweaks, <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> sliding edge loops, insets top and bottom.